# PowerBI performance monitoring

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, microsoft365

As a tenant admin in PowerBI, I've access to all system relevant settings.
However, i can't see all workspace details of my users.

How can i find out automatically, which PowerBI Workspace and User action brings the PowerBI tenant to it's capacity limits (am thinking in on something like a windows-taskmanager for PowerBI showing all system impacts....)?

I have already tried the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-metrics-app but didn't give enough information there.